# Change background loading color in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, colors, email-client, display-settings

In Windows 10, you can change the colors by going to "Control Panel > Personalization > Colors" and select the color you prefer. This also changes the background color of the windows. When you open a Windows app the entire background will be of that color.

For example, if you have selected the color green then it will look like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/upxin3ypec12bx8/windows10-background-color-green.png?dl=0) at first when loading.

But this does not change the color of the Windows Mail background. The Mail app background is always blue. How to change its color to green?

Comment: [How To Change The Mail App Background In Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-change-the-mail-app-background-in-windows-10/)

Comment: [How to Change the Windows 10 Mail App Background - Corey's Computing in Winnipeg](http://www.coreyscomputing.com/2017/02/24/change-windows-10-mail-app-background/)

Comment: The background is still blue after following those instructions in the link. See this video, https://www.dropbox.com/s/pos3ab6dq6lfpu6/windows10-background-color-still-blue.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The Windows default background has no effect on applications that use their own
themes, of which Windows Mail is one.

Such applications need to be configured to use your preferred background color.

As described in the post provided by DavidPostill,
[How To Change The Mail App Background In Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-change-the-mail-app-background-in-windows-10/),
this is done in the account settings:

[image]

Comment: It is still blue. See this video, https://www.dropbox.com/s/pos3ab6dq6lfpu6/windows10-background-color-still-blue.mp4?dl=0

Comment: There are reports that the solid-color option is not working and you must use an image. See for example [this article](https://winaero.com/blog/change-mail-app-background-to-custom-color-in-windows-10/). Windows 10 is changing too fast and not always positively.

Comment: I tried that method and it did not work.

Comment: Nothing works?? Either Microsoft broke Photos, or Photos is badly installed. Try maybe to reboot, in case that changes something, but otherwise I don't know of any additional methods.

Comment: Is Photos connected with the Mail app?

Comment: Mistype : Meant Mail. Sorry.

Comment: I also tried it. In "Control Panel > Apps" you can see the "Mail and Calendar". In that there is a link called "Advanced Options". It provides options to reset the Mail app. I tried it and no changes.

Comment: Microsoft seems to have sabotaged all options. Try maybe to change the theme to Light or Dark to see if something works.